# Cannot get renditions from Adobe Lightroom API

Tags: rest, adobe, lightroom

I am trying to use the [Lightroom APIs](https://developer.adobe.com/lightroom/lightroom-api-docs/api/#operation/getAssetRendition) to retrieve images from my Lightroom Cloud store. I have oauth working, and I can do anything *but* getting a rendition.

I wrote the following script to illustrate my problem. I am able to get my catalog metadata to get the catalog id. I am able to use that catalog id to get an asset id. I am even able to request the metadata for that particular asset, but as soon as I try to get the rendition, I get an error.

```
# (All personal ids/tokens removed)
CLIENTID=MYCLIENTID
TOKEN=ATOKENFROMOAUTH2

CATALOG_ID=MYCATALOID
AN_ASSET_ID=ANASSETID

# These three all work.
CATALOG_URL="https://lr.adobe.io/v2/catalog"
ASSETS_URL="https://lr.adobe.io/v2/catalogs/${CATALOG_ID}/assets"
ASSET_URL="https://lr.adobe.io/v2/catalogs/${CATALOG_ID}/assets/${AN_ASSET_ID}"

# This one does not.
RENDITION_URL="https://lr.adobe.io/v2/catalogs/${CATALOG_ID}/assets/${AN_ASSET_ID}/renditions/2048"

FILE=`mktemp`
wget --content-on-error -S -O$FILE --header="x-api-key: $CLIENTID" --header="authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" $RENDITION_URL
#tail -n +2 $FILE | jsonpp
cat $FILE
```

Output from wget:

```
Resolving lr.adobe.io (lr.adobe.io)... 52.13.231.217, 34.211.127.250, 52.25.171.118
Connecting to lr.adobe.io (lr.adobe.io)|52.13.231.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
  Server: openresty
  Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2022 17:24:56 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 130
  Connection: keep-alive
  X-Result-Code: 1000
  X-Result-Subtype: ResourceNotFoundError
  X-Request-Id: IDREMOVED
  X-Client-Identifier: Wget/1.21.3
  X-Traffic-Type: customer
  X-Account-Id: IDREMOVED
  X-Client-Id: IDREMOVED
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,DELETE,POST,OPTIONS
  Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
  Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  Vary: Origin
Saving to: ‘/var/folders/lh/5yh_y_m92cx8jwhty73958vc0000gn/T/tmp.OR8z0liC’

/var/folders/lh/5yh_y_m9 100%[================================>]     130  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-03-26 13:24:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.

while (1) {}
{"code":1000,"description":"Resource not found","errors":{"type":["not in asset"]},"subtype":"ResourceNotFoundError"}%
```

I have tried this many ways. I have looked at the [Adobe sample code](https://github.com/AdobeDocs/lightroom-partner-apis/blob/master/samples/src/web/pickasset/index.js), but I have been unable to figure this out for myself. Any suggestions welcome and appreciated.

Thanks, y'all!

Comment: Bummer. First time Stack Overflow has ever let me down. :-(

Answer (score 0):

From the HTTP status code 404 and description shows `not found`, you probably need to make a POST request to generate renditions(https://developer.adobe.com/lightroom/lightroom-api-docs/api/#operation/generateRenditions) first before getting renditions from server.

Comment: I _think_ I tried that, but I'll take another look. Thanks.